# Rails: has_many, through not showing in view/index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm writing a simple time tracking app where the user has_many clients and where the client has_many projects.

I want a user to be able to view a list of their projects (for all clients). To implement this, I've set up a has_many, through relationship between the users and projects.

But for some reason I can't get the projects to show up in their index view. There's probably a really simple reason for this that I'm just not noticing, so apologies upfront if that's the case.

Here's the relevant code.

Project index controller:

```
def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
end
```

Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :fee, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, 
  greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100000 }
  validates :client_id, presence: true

end
```

Client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy 
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
    validate :user_id_is_valid

    private 

    def user_id_is_valid
        errors.add(:user_id, "is invalid") unless User.exists?(self.user_id)
    end 
end
```

Relevant part of the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :clients
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="projects-list">
    <% if current_user.projects.any? %>
        <h3>Projects</h3>
        <ul class="project-list">
            <% render @projects %>
        </ul>
        <%= will_paginate @projects %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

_project.html.erb:

```
<li>
    <%= link_to "#{project.name}", '#' %>
</li>
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us the server log when you hit the index page. Things like params, SQL queries are super helpful in cases like this.

Comment: Nothing stands out as suspect here. Server logs would be helpful. Is there data for the `current_user` present?

Comment: I was just about to add in the server logs when I saw the answer below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= render @projects %>
```

Not:

```
<% render @projects %>
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something dumb that I missed. Thanks.